# SailsJS installation on Mac

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I've updated Node and NPM to the latest version. I thin installed Sails using

```
npm install sails -g
```

When I try view the version of or start a new project I get a "-bash: sails: command not found"

```
sails version
sails new test-project
```

Why is Sails not being seen as installed?

Answer (score 0):

Final found my own issues.

rm -rf ~/.npmrc ~/.node

The .npmrc setting prefix key was causing npm to symlink the bin/* for any modules to ~/.node/bin/*, when they should have been ~/.nvm/versions/{node|io.js}/v{version}/bin/*. nvm will set the path to the current node's global node_modules. npm will create the symlink when installing a module that has a bin, if the .npmrc is incorrect, it will to symlink to a nonexistent file.

nvm maintains separate node_modules and npm versions for each version of node that it has installed. so, if you were to switch node versions, the installed modules would be stable to that version. The reason for this is that some node modules use native compilation, like bcrypt. Each version of node has slight variations in how native interfaces are exposed, so nvm keeps your installed modules separate to compensate.